# How to increase count of TextView in Listview item

Tags: android, listview, counter, android-adapter

Hello I have an application that tracks the number of dances and availability of dancers. I have a listview  with custom adapter that shows The dancer's name and a "Start" button. When the start button is clicked: The start button is removed and replaced with a "Stop" Button and a Counterview. Here's what I am trying to accomplish. I would like to make it so that if the start button has been pressed for dancer and they are currently in a dance. I would like to add a "+" button to the activities layout and when clicked should add "1" to every counterview that is visible. after dances have been added and the stop dance button has been selected I'll send that number to the DB to be recorded.

How can I make a button add "1" to the counterview (or TextView) in every listview item? Thank you.

item_services.xml  (Listview Layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3d87d5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvAvail"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:src="@drawable/online"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/feature_button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_dance"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#005906"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stop_dance"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:background="#ab0000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DanceAdapter.java

```
static public Integer count=1;
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final OneDancer oneDancer = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {

    //VIP/Dances Adapter
                else if(type==3) {

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_services, parent, false);

                    final Button button4 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);

                    final TextView counterTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);

                    final Button button6 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button6);

                    final Button button5 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);



                    if(oneDancer.avail.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                    {
                        button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        button6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        counterTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

    if (counterTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                counterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                Log.v("DancerAdapter","counterText visible");
            }
                    //Start Dance Button

                    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    getContext());

                            // set title
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm - Start Dance?");

                            // set dialog message
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage("Confirm Start New dance for " + oneDancer.name + "?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, close
                                            // current activity
                                            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                                            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                                            params.put("action", "makeUnAvailable");
                                            params.put("name", oneDancer.name);

                                            Log.v("SignInActivity","Girl Made unAvailable Response Query");

                                            client.post("http://peekatu.com/", params,
                                                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                                            Log.v("response", response);
                                                            //responseString = response;
                                                            //parseDancerList(response);


                                                            button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                            button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                            button6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                            counterTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                                            if (response.indexOf("OK") > -1) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                                                        "Dance has began for " + oneDancer.name + "?",
                                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                                            }

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
                                                            Log.v("response", "response failed network error");
                                                            //waitncall(true);

                                                        }

                                                    });
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();


                        }
                    });


                    //Stop Dance Button

                    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                            // set title
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm - Stop Dance?");
                            // set dialog message
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage("Confirm End dance for " + oneDancer.name + "?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                                            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                                            params.put("action", "makeAvailable");
                                            params.put("name", oneDancer.name);
                                            //params.put("TimeOut", );


                                            Log.v("SignInActivity","Girl Made Available Response Query");

                                            client.post("http://peekatu.com/", params,
                                                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                                            Log.v("response", response);
                                                            //responseString = response;
                                                            //parseDancerList(response);


                                                            button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                            button6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                            button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                            counterTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                                                            if (response.indexOf("OK") > -1) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                                                        "Dance has Ended for " + oneDancer.name,
                                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                                            }

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
                                                            Log.v("response", "response failed network error");
                                                            //waitncall(true);

                                                        }

                                                    });
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();



                        }
                    });


                //end of if(type3)
                }

static public void setMyCount(int count) {
    DancerAdapter.count = count;

    Log.v("setMyCount",DancerAdapter.count.toString());
}
}
```

ServicesActivity.java

```
Integer count=0;



addDance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {


                                               count++;
                                               DancerAdapter.setMyCount(count);
                                               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                               Log.v("addDanceButton",count.toString());


                                           }
                                       }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `public View getView()`, you should check your `counterTextView`'s visibility to show your count:

```
if (counterTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    counterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
}
```

You will need to pass that count value from your activity with something like this in your adapter:

```
public void setMyCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
```

Since your count is from how many times your +Button is pressed, then its `onClick()` would probably be doing: increment, pass count, refresh list

```
count++;
myAdapter.setMyCount(count);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The process will be like this:

1. click
2. increment
3. pass count
4. refresh list, setView runs
5. textview checks visibility
6. if visible, textview settext

And now your stop-button can get that value from your adapter's count.

Comment: Careful ... `setText(int resId)` is not the method you want to call

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried what you suggested and now my issue is that. I can't call the `setMyCount()` method from the Activity because it requires the method to be static but when I make the method static inside the adapter i get an error for using `this.count = count;` in a static method.

Comment: I was able to get it half way working. my issue now is that all counterview values are being set to the same value.

Comment: Isnt that what you want? All the visible ones set to the same counter? If not, then you need to incorporate your count as part of your dancer obj

Comment: Sorry maybe i wasnt clear. There is a start and stop button on each listview item. When start is clicked the counterview is shown and should go up `onClick()` if stop is clicked and then start is clicked again the counter should return to zero and then begin counting again but other listview items should keep their current value.

Comment: can you show me how i would add this into the dancer object please?

Comment: Bump...help please, i cant figure out how to great a method to increase the count of the dancer object